# Google Maps API v3: Can I setZoom after fitBounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I have a set of points I want to plot on an embedded Google Map (API v3).  I'd like the bounds to accommodate all points unless the zoom level is too low (i.e., zoomed out too much).  My approach has been like this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// extend bounds with each point

gmap.fitBounds(bounds); 
gmap.setZoom( Math.max(6, gmap.getZoom()) );
```

This doesn't work.  The last line "gmap.setZoom()" doesn't change the zoom level of the map if called directly after fitBounds.

Is there a way to get the zoom level of a bounds without applying it to the map?  Other ideas to solve this?

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/4523023/using-setzoom-after-using-fitbounds-with-google-maps-api-v3

Answer (score 373, accepted):

**Edit**: See Matt Diamond's comment below.

Got it! Try this:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
  if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16); 
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
});
```

Modify to your needs.

Comment: Great solution, totally saved me a lot of a trouble. Just wanted to add that you could simplify it further by using the addListenerOnce method... that way, you don't have to save the listener and manually remove it, as the method will take care of that for you.

Comment: This has the behavior of seeing the map "skip". Instead listen for the "zoom_change" event, and set it up before calling fitBounds(). See my answer below

Comment: Thanks! google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() { } --> worked great for my maps package for SugarCRM.

Comment: The listener doesn't get triggered for me. I tried this in document.ready and window.load. Any ideas? map object is OK and tried addListener also: `  var map=$("#js-main-map-canvas");
  var listener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() { 
  alert('hello');
});`

Comment: Henrik, try $("#js-main-map-canvas")[0] or $("#js-main-map-canvas").get(0);

Comment: Rafael, didn't help. I do get an object with my code, with yours I get a HTMLdivelement. This is in document.ready.

Comment: @Henrik Sorry for the late reply. With your code, you get an object that's not a Google Map object but a jQuery object (or whatever they are called). Try to use the pointer/reference that you get when you create the map, like so: var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap-canvas"), options);

Comment: in case `map.fitBounds(bounds);` didn't update the map (in my case i was merging some points and sometimes it does not change the bounds) then ideal event doesn't get triggered at that time, it gets triggered after next change_bound event may that be a manual operation.

this is how i did it:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33050755/3666966

Comment: If fitBounds isn't causing the 'bounds_changed' event to fire, then use 'center_changed' instead. It changes every time the fitBounds() function is called. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761416/google-maps-fitbounds-callback/35766176#35766176

Comment: Or you can set the `maxZoom` option when you first initiate the map (`new google.maps.Map(...)`).

Comment: With event "bounds_changed" is zoom animations more quick and smooth.

Comment: You can use `addListnerOnce` to avoid the logic to remove it.

Comment: Honestly, this fixed my problem with just pasting - thanks a lot!

Comment: Still relevant!!

Answer (score 83):

I solved a similar problem in one of my apps.  I was a little confused by your description of the problem, but I think you have the same goal I had...

In my app I wanted to plot a one or more markers and ensure the map was showing them all.  The problem was, if I relied solely on the fitBounds method, then the zoom-level would be maxed out when there was a single point - that was no good.

The solution was to use fitBounds when there was many points, and setCenter+setZoom when there was only one point.

```
if (pointCount > 1) {
  map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
}
else if (pointCount == 1) {
  map.setCenter(mapBounds.getCenter());
  map.setZoom(14);
}
```

Comment: Your answer have solve my problem with Google Maps V3.  Thanks!

Comment: I was trying the same approach by myself but it did not work because I wasn't invoking setCenter() before setting the zoom... I'm still wondering why this step is needed, but anyway now it works... thanks a lot Jim!

Comment: This is nice because you don't have to deal with the animation jump of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 46):

I have come to this page multiple times to get the answer, and while all the existing answers were super helpful, they did not solve my problem exactly.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(googleMap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var oldZoom = googleMap.getZoom();
    googleMap.setZoom(oldZoom - 1); //Or whatever
});
```

Basically I found that the 'zoom_changed' event prevented the UI of the map from "skipping" which happened when i waited for the 'idle' event.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Excellent, I had the 'skipping / auto-zooming' behavior as well. Just as a note for other readers: be sure to use "addListenerOnce" as Benjamin does above instead of "addListener", or break your head on why your browser crashes all the time ;-)

Comment: Also note that the listener should be added before calling `fitBounds()` if using `zoom_changed`

Comment: Thanks for this, seems like v4 should have a fitBounds(bounds,minZoomLevel) :)

Comment: Benjamin, I think it is better to use `bounds_changed`, because `zoom_changed` doesn't have to be triggered in the case when `fitBounds` keeps the zoom level. My attempt http://jsfiddle.net/rHeMp/10/ doesn't confirm that, but one should not rely on undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

I’ve just fixed this by setting maxZoom in advance, then removing it afterwards. For example:

```
map.setOptions({ maxZoom: 15 });
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setOptions({ maxZoom: null });
```

Comment: The best solution by far for preventing zooming in too much. Simple and intuitive. No drawing and re-drawing of map.

Comment: This is indeed the best walkaround so far.

Comment: I found that this doesn't work if you reset maxZoom immediately after calling fitBounds, because the zoom happens asynchronously (so maxZoom is back to null by the time it zooms in).  Waiting until "idle" to reset it would fix this though I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);

// CHANGE ZOOM LEVEL AFTER FITBOUNDS
zoomChangeBoundsListener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
  if (this.getZoom()){
    this.setZoom(15);
  }
});
setTimeout(function(){
  google.maps.event.removeListener(zoomChangeBoundsListener)
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, I'm assuming you want all your points to be visible on the map with the highest possible zoom level. I accomplished this by initializing the zoom level of the map to **16**(not sure if it's the highest possible zoom level on V3).

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 16,
  center: marker_point,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Then after that I did the bounds stuff:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// You can have a loop here of all you marker points
// Begin loop
bounds.extend(marker_point);
// End loop

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Result:
 Success!

Answer (score 4):

I saw many incorrect or too complicated solutions, so decided to post a **working, elegant solution**.

The reason `setZoom()` doesn't work as you expect is that `fitBounds()` is asynchronous, so it gives no guarantee that it would immediately update the zoom, but your call to `setZoom()` relies on that.

What you might consider is setting the `minZoom` map option before calling `fitBounds()` and then clearing it after it completes (so that users can still zoom out manually if they want to):

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
// ... (extend bounds with all points you want to fit)

// Ensure the map does not get too zoomed out when fitting the bounds.
gmap.setOptions({minZoom: 6});
// Clear the minZoom only after the map fits the bounds (note that
// fitBounds() is asynchronous). The 'idle' event fires when the map
// becomes idle after panning or zooming.
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(gmap, 'idle', function() {
  gmap.setOptions({minZoom: null});
});

gmap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

In addition, if you want to also limit the max zoom, you can apply the same trick with the `maxZoom` property.

See the [MapOptions docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions).

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
gmap.setZoom(24); //this looks a high enough zoom value
gmap.fitBounds(bounds); //now the fitBounds should make the zoom value only less
```

This will use the smaller of 24 and the necessary zoom level according to your code, however it probably changes the zoom anyway and doesn't care about how much you zoomed out.

Comment: I hate to say this, but as weird as this answer looked like, it's the only thing that worked so far and I've been searching for 4-5hrs on a 3 days span. Will still be searching for a better solution though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I was able to solve it using the following code.  This listener (`google.maps.addListenerOnce()`) event will only get fired once, right after `map.fitBounds()` is executed.  So, there is no need to

1. Keep track of and manually remove the listener, or
2. Wait until the map is `idle`.

It sets the appropriate zoom level initially and allows the user to zoom in and out past the initial zoom level because the event listener has expired.  For example, if only `google.maps.addListener()` was called, then the user would *never* be able to zoom-in past the stated zoom level (in the case, 4).  Since we implemented `google.maps.addListenerOnce()`, the user will be able to zoom to any level he/she chooses.

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);

var zoom_level_for_one_marker = 4;

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event){
   if (this.getZoom() >= zoom_level_for_one_marker){  
       this.setZoom(zoom_level_for_one_marker) 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, needed to fit many markers on the map.
This solved my case:

1. Declare bounds
2. Use scheme provided by koderoid (for each marker set `bounds.extend(objLatLng)`)
3. Execute fitbounds AFTER map is completed:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() { 
       map.fitBounds( bounds );
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution that does the check before calling `fitBounds` so you don't zoom in and suddenly zoom out

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// extend bounds with each point

var minLatSpan = 0.001;
if (bounds.toSpan().lat() > minLatSpan) {
    gmap.fitBounds(bounds); 
} else {
    gmap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    gmap.setZoom(16);
}
```

You'll have to play around with the minLatSpan variable a bit to get it where you want. It will vary based on both zoom-level and the dimensions of the map canvas.

You could also use longitude instead of latitude

Comment: Works for me, but I'm not using minLatSpan - I need to set zoom only when 1 marker is in the map. Therefore I'm only checking if there're more then 1 markers.

Answer (score 1):

In this function, you need to dynamically add metadata to store the geometry type only because the function accepts any geometry.

"fitGeometries" is a JSON function extending a map object.

"geometries" is an generic javascript array not an MVCArray().

```
geometry.metadata = { type: "point" };
var geometries = [geometry];

fitGeometries: function (geometries) {
    // go and determine the latLngBounds...
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < geometries.length; i++) {
        var geometry = geometries[i];
        switch (geometry.metadata.type)
        {
            case "point":
                var point = geometry.getPosition();
                bounds.extend(point);
                break;
            case "polyline":
            case "polygon": // Will only get first path
                var path = geometry.getPath();
                for (var j = 0; j < path.getLength(); j++) {
                    var point = path.getAt(j);
                    bounds.extend(point);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    this.getMap().fitBounds(bounds);
},
```

Comment: Alternately, I did all the work without knowing that there is an extend() method on the LatLngBounds object.  This would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to ensure the zoom level does not exceed a set level so that I know satellite images will be available.

Add a listener to the `zoom_changed` event.
This has the added benefit of controlling the zoom control on the UI also.

Only execute `setZoom` if you need to, so an `if` statement is preferable to `Math.max` or to `Math.min`

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { 
      if ( map.getZoom() > 19 ) { 
        map.setZoom(19); 
      } 
    });
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( ... your bounds ... )
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

To prevent zooming out too far:

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { 
      if ( map.getZoom() < 6 ) { 
        map.setZoom(6); 
      } 
    });
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( ... your bounds ... )
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 1):

this work's for me with API v3 but with setting fixed zoom:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
// extend bounds with each point

gmap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); 
gmap.setZoom( 6 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Like me, if you are not willing to play with listeners, this is a simple solution i came up with:
Add a method on map which works strictly according to your requirements like this one :

```
    map.fitLmtdBounds = function(bounds, min, max){
        if(bounds.isEmpty()) return;
        if(typeof min == "undefined") min = 5;
        if(typeof max == "undefined") max = 15;

        var tMin = this.minZoom, tMax = this.maxZoom;
        this.setOptions({minZoom:min, maxZoom:max});
        this.fitBounds(bounds);
        this.setOptions({minZoom:tMin, maxZoom:tMax});
    }
```

then you may call **`map.fitLmtdBounds(bounds)`** instead of `map.fitBounds(bounds)` to set the bounds under defined zoom range... or **`map.fitLmtdBounds(bounds,3,5)`** to override the zoom range..

Answer (score 1):

`Promise` based solution based on LGT's answer. Useful if you're having to do this more than once.

```
fitMapToBounds(map, bounds) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", () =>
            resolve(map.getZoom()));
    });
}
```

Then use it like:

```
const zoom = await fitMapToBounds(map, bounds);
map.setZoom(Math.min(zoom, 14));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
// Find out what the map's zoom level is
zoom = map.getZoom();
if (zoom == 1) {
  // If the zoom level is that low, means it's looking around the
world.
  // Swap the sw and ne coords
  viewportBounds = new
google.maps.LatLngBounds(results[0].geometry.location, initialLatLng);
  map.fitBounds(viewportBounds);
}
```

If this will helpful to you.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to suggest it, but if you *must* try - first call

`gmap.fitBounds(bounds);`

Then create a new Thread/AsyncTask, have it sleep for 20-50ms or so and then call

`gmap.setZoom( Math.max(6, gmap.getZoom()) );`

from the UI thread (use a handler or the `onPostExecute` method for AsyncTask).

I don't know if it works, just a suggestion. Other than that you'd have to somehow calculate the zoom level from your points yourself, check if it's too low, correct it and then just call `gmap.setZoom(correctedZoom)`

Answer (score 0):

After calculation of the boundries you can check the distance between upper left and down right corner; then you can understand the zoom level by testing the distance (if distance is too far zoom level would be low) then you can select wheter using setbound method or setZoom..

Answer (score 0):

If 'bounds_changed' is not firing correctly (sometimes Google doesn't seem to accept coordinates perfectly), then consider using 'center_changed' instead.

The 'center_changed' event fires every time fitBounds() is called, although it runs immediately and not necessarily after the map has moved.

In normal cases, 'idle' is still the best event listener, but this may help a couple people running into weird issues with their fitBounds() calls.

See [google maps fitBounds callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761416/google-maps-fitbounds-callback/35766176#35766176)

Answer (score 0):

To chime in with another solution - I found that the "listen for bounds_changed event and then set new zoom" approach didn't work reliably for me. I think that I was sometimes calling `fitBounds` before the map had been fully initialized, and the initialization was causing a bounds_changed event that would use up the listener, before `fitBounds` changed the boundaries and zoom level. I ended up with this code, which seems to work so far:

```
// If there's only one marker, or if the markers are all super close together,
// `fitBounds` can zoom in too far. We want to limit the maximum zoom it can
// use.
//
// `fitBounds` is asynchronous, so we need to wait until the bounds have
// changed before we know what the new zoom is, using an event handler.
//
// Sometimes this handler gets triggered by a different event, before
// `fitBounds` takes effect; that particularly seems to happen if the map
// hasn't been fully initialized yet. So we don't immediately remove the
// listener; instead, we wait until the 'idle' event, and remove it then.
//
// But 'idle' might happen before 'bounds_changed', so we can't set up the
// removal handler immediately. Set it up in the first event handler.

var removeListener = null;
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', () => {
  console.log(map.getZoom());
  if (map.getZoom() > 15) {
    map.setZoom(15);
  }

  if (!removeListener) {
    removeListener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', () => {
      console.log('remove');
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest solution was this:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);

function set_zoom() {
    if(map.getZoom()) {map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);}
    else {setTimeout(set_zoom, 5);}
}
setTimeout(set_zoom, 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
    var oldZoom = map.getZoom(); 
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(parseInt(oldZoom) + 1);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

All I did is:

```
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
```

And it works on V3 API.

Comment: map.setCenter accepts only one attribute, latlng, and map has no function like getBoundsZoomLevel

Comment: I thought there is a function like getBoundsZoomLevel after I see this post, and I am disappointed after I realized there is not.

Comment: i think getBoundsZoomLevel() was available in Google Maps V2 API and not in V3 API