# Setting map bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-groups

I have a map which I would like to stay within certain bounds. I have allowed for 2 zoom levels 5 and 8. On zoom level 5 I was able to keep the map from moving by setting the center of the map to adjust by using the setCenter() function on the event of a drag. When I am zoomed in at zoom level 8 I would like to prevent users from dragging the map outside designated limits. The limits are the bounds at zoom level 5. I have tried a few things but with no avail. When I used fitbounds() it kicked me back to zoom level 5. I basically just want to limit how far you can go on the map. Any help would be appreciated.

G

Answer (score 0):

There is a method posted here http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm that works with v2 of the Google Maps API.  The technique should work with v3 as well.  View source on the example page.

Also see the duplicate question here for refinements on the above method:  [Google Maps API V3: limit map bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901611/google-maps-api-v3-limit-map-bounds)