# Change map boundaries google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Does anyone know how to change the boundaries of a map with the google maps api? I have a map currently that shows the full world and if I zoom out it shows multiple copies of the full world. The problem is that I only want to show north america, and I only want to show it once. Can anybody help out? Thanks!

Comment: show us your current codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate: [Google Maps API V3: limit map bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901611/google-maps-api-v3-limit-map-bounds)

---

There's no API to restrict map boundary in Google Maps API. You may can accept [external solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901611/google-maps-api-v3-limit-map-bounds#answer-4533093), or consider using other map library like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com), which supports max-extent feature.