# Google Maps API v3 not loading without fitbounds, zooming causing infinite loop/stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, stack-overflow

Previous question here:
[stack overflow with Google maps API (IE7 IE8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724212/stack-overflow-with-google-maps-api-ie7-ie8)
I found the following question in the mean time: [Google Maps API v3: Can I setZoom after fitBounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437683/google-maps-api-v3-can-i-setzoom-after-fitbounds)

The solution there works just fine, when I have more than one marker on the map. However when I visit a subpage of groupbke.young.netaffinity.net eg. https://groupbke.young.netaffinity.net/hotels/ireland/dublin/dublin/young-testing-hotel-liege/specials/bed-and-breakfast
the map will only load if map.fitBounds() is called. On the other hand, even if the map is not loaded, it will throw a stack overflow error when I scroll above the map canvas.
Will throw a stack overflow anyway, if I try to use setZoom.

Any ideas?

```
var hoteldata = [
['Young Testing Hotel - Liège', 53.33932, -6.261427, '<div class="nearby-hotel"> <h1><a href="/hotels/ireland/dublin/dublin/young-testing-hotel-liege">Young Testing Hotel - Liège</a></h1> <div class="star-rating-1"></div><div class="clear"></div> <div class="nearby-hotel-image l"> <a href="/hotels/ireland/dublin/dublin/young-testing-hotel-liege"><img src="http://groupbke.young.netaffinity.net/bookings/images/imagecache/3/0C9DBC143E18ED64059C1696A52D2941-60x60.jpg" border="1" class="imagetype1"/></a> </a> </div> <div class="nearby-hotel-description l">  <a class="nearby-hotel-desc" href="/hotels/ireland/dublin/dublin/young-testing-hotel-liege">Dublin\'s most luxurious design hotel is located in the heart of the city. Experience the best of both worlds when staying at this chic haven, to one side the tranquility and calm of St Stephen\'s Green and to the other, Grafton Street, Dublin\'s finest shopping avenue.    From its central location, in amongst this buzzing vibrant city it is an easy stroll to explore the leading cultural, historical and leisure attractions. Or just step out to the chic shopping, high energy bars, fine dining restaurants and chattering Cafes.</a> <a href="/hotels/ireland/dublin/dublin/young-testing-hotel-liege" class="btn-small">Book Now</a> </div> <div class="clear"></div> </div>', 4]
];
function initialize(mapid) {
var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
};
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapid), myOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markers = [];

for (i = 0; i < hoteldata.length; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(hoteldata[i][1], hoteldata[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(latLng);
    var img = '/images/hotel-marker.png';
    if (hoteldata[i][4] == 2) {
        img = '/images/country-marker.png';
    }
    if (hoteldata[i][4] == 3) {
        img = '/images/guesthouse-marker.png';
    }
    if (hoteldata[i][4] == 4) {
        img = '/images/hotel-self-marker.png';
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    icon: img,
    shadow: '/images/marker-shadow.png'
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, hoteldata[i][3]);

}

var clusterStyles = [
  {
    opt_textColor: 'white',
    url: '/images/m3-blue.png',
    height: 65,
    width: 64
  },
 {
    opt_textColor: 'white',
    url: '/images/m3-green.png',
    height: 65,
    width: 64
  },
 {
    opt_textColor: 'white',
    url: '/images/m3-orange.png',
    height: 65,
    width: 64 
  }
];

var mcOptions = {
    styles: clusterStyles,
    maxZoom:14

};


if (markers.length>1){
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            var oldZoom = map.getZoom();
            map.setZoom(oldZoom + (-7)); //Or whatever
    });
} else if (markers.length == 1){
    markers[0].setMap(map);
    //google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'zoom_changed');
    //google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        //  var oldZoom = map.getZoom();
        //  map.setZoom(oldZoom + (-7)); //Or whatever
    //  setTimeout('roomSetter(globalmap,globalzoom)',300);
    //});
    //google.maps.event.trigger(map,'zoom_changed');
    //google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'zoom_changed');
    //map.fitBounds(bounds);
    //var oldZoom = map.getZoom();
    //map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    //map.setZoom(oldZoom+(-7));
    //map.setZoom(3);
    //globalmap=map;
    //globalzoom=map.getZoom()+(-7);
    //setTimeout('zoomSetter(globalmap,globalzoom)',300);
}
}

var globalmap;
var globalzoom;

function zoomSetter(map, zoom){
//map.setZoom(zoom);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) { 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    infowindow.setContent(html); 
    infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    }); 
} 

function initmaps() {
initialize('map_canvas');
initialize('map_thumb');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initmaps);
```

I've set up 3 testpages to demonstrate the problem:

http://groupbke.young.netaffinity.net/maptest1.html

this has the setZoom() function and throws a stackoverflow error, even though this should be correct

http://groupbke.young.netaffinity.net/maptest2.html

this does nothing beyond adding the marker to the map. scroll zooming on the map still throws a stack error.

http://groupbke.young.netaffinity.net/maptest3.html

this has fitBound(), which in theory is not good, but works. can NOT adjust the zoom level after that, or it will throw a stackoverflow error. scroll zooming works.

Comment: Your link has major problems (not map related, looks like it can't load lots of the external files, including the required css): http://groupbke.young.netaffinity.net/hotels/ireland/dublin/dublin/young-testing-hotel-liege/specials/bed-and-breakfast

Comment: Your certificate is invalid (wrong site) and out of date (expired a year ago), so browsers won't connect over HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was missing from the answer from my previous question was that an initial zoom level and center has to be set.

```
    var myOptions = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoom:22,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.820645,-0.137376)
    };
```

Also had to change the event to '**idle**' on the multi marker zooming adjustment.

```
if (markers.length>1){
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        var oldZoom = map.getZoom();
        map.setZoom(oldZoom + (-7)); //Or whatever
    });
}
```

Works like a charm after that.

Answer (score 0):

When you have only one hotel, you create a `LatLngBounds` object containing only one point:

```
for (i = 0; i < hoteldata.length; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(hoteldata[i][1], hoteldata[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(latLng);
...}
```

but you then do a `map.fitBounds(bounds)` — this attempts an infinite zoom. While it's arguable that the API should be able to cope with that, it's equally arguable that it will attempt to do exactly what you tell it. It's possible that IE will behave differently to Firefox and other browsers.

Where you have commented out the `fitBounds()` in your quoted code in the question, that *is* present in your online page. Since that line only applies to instances where one marker is involved and the `bounds` object is a single point, I would replace it with a simple `setZoom()` instead.

```
map.setZoom(16);
```

Comment: sorry, I've been trying to find a solution has the slight change and lots of commented stuff. actually the way it was with fitBounds(), it works fine on IE and FF as well. the problem is without fitBounds(), I get nothing displayed and it will cause the loops and stackoverflows on zooming as it is now. putting in setZoom() will trigger an overflow on load

Comment: Fine. Could you supply a link to a demonstrator please? It doesn't have to be a real live page on your site; it could be a temporary page. Whichever, please make sure that (a) you **don't play with the code;** (b) there is enough code quoted here in the question to create a standalone demonstrator which will also fail.

Comment: Thanks, put 3 links at the end of the question. I won't play with those.