# Make child DIV scrollable

Tags: html, css

I'm working in the [this code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39041929/site/Testes/FusionTable.html) to have a child DIV to scroll within the parent's bounds, even when the browser's windows height is changed.

[I'm trying to get rid of this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPArN.png)

I only want to scroll the `#FilterBox` DIV and not the TITLE.
For the parent height it must be `height: calc(91% - 80px);`

How can I achieve this?

Take a look in the CSS part of the code snippet:
The parent DIV  is the `#ParentDiv` and the child DIV is the `#FilterBox`.

```js
function initMap() {   //http://devfestmtm.appspot.com/#1
  var mapProp = {
   zoom: 4,
   center: {lat: 0 , lng: 0},
   
   mapTypeControl: true,
   mapTypeControlOptions: 
   {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
    mapTypeIds: 
    [
    google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 
    google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 
    google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
    ]
   },

   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
   
   
   zoomControl: true,  //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437683/google-maps-api-v3-can-i-setzoom-after-fitbounds
   zoomControlOptions: 
   {
    style: 'LARGE',
    position: 'RIGHT_CENTER',
   },
   
   scaleControl: true,
   draggable: true,
   
   rotateControl: true,
   overviewMapControl: true,
   
   fullscreenControl: false,
   streetViewControl: false,
   scrollwheel: true,
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp); 
 }
```

```css
 html,body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px
 }
 #map{
  height: 100%;
 }
 #ParentDiv{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius : 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(132,132,132,0.7);
  padding:0 5px 5px 5px; 
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  position:fixed;
  min-width: 150px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px; 
  margin-left: 7px; 
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align:top;
  display: block;

  /* Firefox */
  height: -moz-calc(91% - 80px);
  /* WebKit */
  height: -webkit-calc(91% - 80px);
  /* Opera */
  height: -o-calc(91% - 80px);
  /* Standard */
  height: calc(91% - 80px);
 }

 #FilterBox{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 7px; 
    padding-right: 20px;    
    display:block;
    font-size: 11px;
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
 
 <!---  Change ParentDiv style to none and psqGeral unchecked --->
 <div id="ParentDiv" style="display:block;">
 <h1 class="DivTitle" style="background-color:gold; text-align:center;">TITLE<br></h1>

 <div id="FilterBox">

  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome1' value='ValueA' > SomeText - Some Text1
  </label>
  
  <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_1'>+</span></a>]</font> 
  <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_1'>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1'  value='Value1' > SomeText - Some Text1SomeText - Some Text1SomeText - Some Text1<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1'  value='Value2' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome2' value='ValueB' > SomeText - Some Text2
  </label>
  <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_2'>+</span></a>]</font>
  <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_2'>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome3' value='ValueB' > SomeText - Some Text2
  </label>
  <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_3'>+</span></a>]</font>
  <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_3'>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome4' value='ValueB' > SomeText - Some Text2
  </label>
  <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_4'>+</span></a>]</font>
  <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_4'>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome5' value='ValueB' > SomeText - Some Text2
  </label>
  <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_5'>+</span></a>]</font>
  <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_5'>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome6' value='ValueB' > SomeText - Some Text2
  </label>
  <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_6'>+</span></a>]</font>
  <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_6'>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome7' value='ValueB' > SomeText - Some Text2
  </label>
  <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_7'>+</span></a>]</font>
  <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_7'>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7'  value='Value3' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7'  value='Value4' > SomeText - Some Text<br>
   </label>
  </div>
  
  <br>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Links to external sites can get lost/change and when that happens it will make this question useless for future users, so post a minimal, working code snippet that reproduce the issue.

Comment: @LGSon ok, I'll do that right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `calc(100% - 80px)` on the `#Filterbox`, not the `#ParentDiv`

```js
function initMap() { //http://devfestmtm.appspot.com/#1
  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },

    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
      mapTypeIds: [
        google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      ]
    },

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,


    zoomControl: true, //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437683/google-maps-api-v3-can-i-setzoom-after-fitbounds
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: 'LARGE',
      position: 'RIGHT_CENTER',
    },

    scaleControl: true,
    draggable: true,

    rotateControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,

    fullscreenControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#ParentDiv {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(132, 132, 132, 0.7);
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 150px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  height: calc(91% - 80px);
}
#FilterBox {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<!---  Change ParentDiv style to none and psqGeral unchecked --->
<div id="ParentDiv" style="display:block;">
  <h1 class="DivTitle" style="background-color:gold; text-align:center;">TITLE<br></h1>

  <div id="FilterBox">

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome1' value='ValueA'>SomeText - Some Text1
    </label>

    <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_1'>+</span></a>]</font> 
    <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_1'>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1' value='Value1'>SomeText - Some Text1SomeText - Some Text1SomeText - Some Text1
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1' value='Value2'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome1' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome2' value='ValueB'>SomeText - Some Text2
    </label>
    <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_2'>+</span></a>]</font>
    <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_2'>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome2' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome3' value='ValueB'>SomeText - Some Text2
    </label>
    <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_3'>+</span></a>]</font>
    <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_3'>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome3' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome4' value='ValueB'>SomeText - Some Text2
    </label>
    <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_4'>+</span></a>]</font>
    <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_4'>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome4' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome5' value='ValueB'>SomeText - Some Text2
    </label>
    <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_5'>+</span></a>]</font>
    <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_5'>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome5' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome6' value='ValueB'>SomeText - Some Text2
    </label>
    <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_6'>+</span></a>]</font>
    <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_6'>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome6' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type='checkbox' class='psqGeral' name='psqNome7' value='ValueB'>SomeText - Some Text2
    </label>
    <font style='font-size: 13px'>[<a style='text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;'    ><span id='span_classe_especifica_7'>+</span></a>]</font>
    <div style='display:display' class='classeEspecifica' id='div_classe_especifica_7'>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7' value='Value3'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' class='psqEspecifica' name='psqNome7' value='Value4'>SomeText - Some Text
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>

    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GeoMaps Not when I tested it, but the whole `ParentDiv` moves below the viewport when resize its height, and the reason for that is the `top: 40px`, so I added back the `height: calc(91% - 80px);` on the `ParentDiv`, or you need change the `top: 40px` to percent

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. Adjust the height and width to match your needs.

```
#FilterBox{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 7px; 
    padding-right: 20px;    
    display:block;
    font-size: 11px;
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: But if you change the Browser's window height, the child DIV still goes further than the parent height. Look what happen with your code too: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39041929/1.PNG